# Why do I get sibling's(next image) alt value twice on click event?

Tags: jquery, events

I want to say sorry for my bad english

I am currently working with an worldcup website.

My task is create a js code which introduces stadiums to users

HTML which I have made:

```
            <section id="CitiesStadium">
            <section class="cities col-md-4">
                <ul>
                    <li>Ekaterinburg</li>
                    <li>Kaliningrad</li>
                    <li>Kazan</li>
                    <li>Moscow</li>
                    <li>Nizhny Novgorod</li>
                    <li>Rostov-on-don<li>
                    <li>Saint Petersburg</li>
                    <li>Samara</li>
                    <li>Saransk</li>
                    <li>Sochi</li>
                </ul>
            </section>
            <section class="cityStadium">
                <h2>Stadiums</h2>
                <img class="rounded col-md-3" data-city="Moscow" alt="Luzhniki Stadium" title="Luzhniki Stadium,Moscow"src="too long">
                <img class="rounded col-md-3" data-city="Moscow"alt="Spartak Arena" title="Spartak Arena, Moscow" src="too long">
                <img class="rounded col-md-3" data-city="Saint Petersburg" alt="Saint Petersburg Stadium" title="Saint Petersburg Stadium, St petersburg" src="too long">
                <img class="rounded col-md-3" data-city="Sochi" alt="Fisht Stadium" title="Fisht Stadium, Sochi" src="too long">
                <img class="rounded col-md-3" data-city="Ekaterinburg" alt="Ekaterinburg Arena" title="Ekaterinburg Arena, Ekaterinburg" src="too long">
                <img class="rounded col-md-3" data-city="Kazan" alt="Kazan Arena" title="Kazan Arena, Kazan" src="too long">
                <img class="rounded col-md-3" data-city="Kaliningrad" alt="Kalinngrad Stadium" title="Kaliningrad Stadium, Kaliningrad" src="too long">
                <img class="rounded col-md-3" data-city="Nizhny Novgorod" alt="Nizhny Novgorod Stadium" title="Nizhny Novgorod Stadium, Nizhny Novgorod" src="too long">
                <img class="rounded col-md-3" data-city="Rostov-on-don" alt="Rostov Arena" title="Rostov Arena, Rostov-on-don" src="too long">
                <img class="rounded col-md-3" data-city="Samara" alt="Samara Arena" title="Samara Arena, Samara" src="too long">
                <img class="rounded col-md-3" data-city="Saransk" alt="Mordovia Arena" title="Mordovia Arena, Saransk" src="too long">
                <img class="rounded col-md-3" data-city="Volgograd" alt="Volgograd Stadium" title="Volgograd Stadium, Volgograd" src="too long">
            </section>
        </section>
```

JS file:

```
(function($){
    $('section li').on('click',function(){
        var thisLi = $(this);
         getCityStadiumInfo(thisLi);
    }); 
}(jQuery))
 //some codes

function getCityStadiumInfo(list){
   var stadiumName;
   var listText = list.text();
   var informationRubric = $('<h2 class="stadiumName">'+listText+'</h2>');
   var stadiumDescription = $('<div class="stadiumDescription">');
   var stadiumCapacity = $('<span class="capacity">');

   $('section.cityStadium h2').text(listText).hide().fadeIn(600);
   var $stadiumImg = $('.cityStadium img');
   $stadiumImg.removeClass('col-md-3').addClass('col-md-9').addClass('invisible');
  $stadiumImg.each(function(){
    if($(this).data('city')==listText){
        $(this).removeClass('invisible').hide().fadeIn(600);
        if(listText == 'Moscow'){
            $('img[alt="Spartak Arena"]').addClass('invisible');
            $('section.cityStadium img[alt="Luzhniki Stadium"]').on('click',function(){
                $(this).fadeOut(200,function(){
                    $(this).addClass('invisible');

                    $('img[alt="Spartak Arena"]').removeClass('invisible').hide().fadeIn(200);//equivalent to $(this).next().removeClass()...;
                    stadiumName = $('img[alt="Spartak Arena"]').attr('alt');
                    console.log(stadiumName);
                });

            });

        }
    }
});
   stadiumName = $stadiumImg.not('.invisible').attr('alt');
  console.log(stadiumName);
 }
```

So when I click on section li, just an image with data-city value as text of li tag will be displayed on right. But, there are two images which have Moscow as `data-city`. That's why I added second on click event inside each loop to show second image.

Every images have name of stadium as `alt` value. I need get them but problem is,  I need `attr()` method inside `click` listener to get `alt` value of second Moscow image (Spartak Arena) but this code returns `alt` value twice.

Why do I get `alt` value twice? How should I do if I want get that just one?

class `invisible` == `display.none`

Comment: You're performing `$('section li').on('click',function(){` on page load which will create one binding on the lis.  Inside the event handler you are performing `$('section.cityStadium img[alt="Luzhniki Stadium"]').on('click',function(){` which is creating one binding on those elements.  Every time you click an li, new **additional** bindings will be added to the elements matched for the second binding, resulting in duplicate bindings.

Comment: The double happens because you bind the handler inside the `$stadiumImg.each` so for each `moscow` image you bind the handler. So 2 images means 2 times bound handler and 2 logs. If you had 3 images you would get it 3 times. But as @taplar mentioned if you click on moscow a second time, then you will get it another 2 times. Each time you click you add 2 more handlers.

Comment: @Taplar  thank you!!

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli thank you!!